# Which methods does curl use in these two cases for authentication, GET or POST?

Tags: curl

You can opt to either insert the user and password in the URL or you can provide them separately:

```
curl http://user:password@example.org/
```

or

```
curl -u user:password http://example.org/
```

Which methods does curl use in the two cases, GET or POST?

Does curl generate the same HTTP request in both cases? If not, which one is less secure?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GET` v. `POST` has nothing to do with authentication. See [When should I use GET or POST method? What's the difference between them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/504947/4500798)

In both cases here, `curl` uses basic authentication (the default) and a `GET` request. You can see exactly what `curl` does by adding the `-v` option: this will cause `curl` to display its requests and the responses it gets (limited to headers), in addition to the response body it outputs by default.

If you want to use a more secure authentication mechanism, you can specify it explicitly (`--digest` or `--negotiate` typically), or use the `--anyauth` option to tell `curl` to figure out the most secure authentication mechanism it can use.

Comment: docs: `-X ... The specified  request will  be  used instead of the method otherwise used (which defaults to GET).`

Comment: Right, although usually you’d rely on `curl` doing the “right thing” depending on other options (*e.g.* it will automatically switch to `POST` if you add a `-d` or `-F` option).

Comment: Does "limited to headers" apply to response? `-v` will show the body of a response, correct?

Comment: `curl` always the body of the response by default. `-v` specifies additional output. (I’ll update my answer.)